# Group By each date in Django 2

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-aggregation

I have a model called `Log` which has a datetime field `created_at`.

What I want to do is to calculate the number of `Log`s for each date.

I tried to do this:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

Log.objects.annotate(date=TruncDate('created_at')).values('date').annotate(c=Count('id'))
```

This is giving me the following:

```
{'date': datetime.date(2018, 1, 17), 'count': 1}, {'date': datetime.date(2018, 1, 17), 'count': 1}, {'date': datetime.date(2018, 1, 17), 'count': 2}
```

That is, the `date` is not unique.

The result I want would be this:

```
{'date': datetime.date(2018, 1, 17), 'count': 4}, {'date': datetime.date(2018, 1, 18), 'count': 2}
```

How could approach this problem?

Comment: @Rakesh that is an error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'date' into field.` and if I change that to `created_at`, it gives nothing.

Comment: Log.objects.annotate(date=TruncDate('created_at')).values('d‌​ate').distinct().annotate(c=Count(‌​'id'))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set default ordering in your `Log` model extra field will be added to GROUP BY section of your query, and it can cause this problem. Try to remove ordering.

```
Log.objects.order_by().annotate(date=TruncDate('created_at')).values('date').annotate(c=Count('id'))
```

Comment: That's exactly it. I looked at the underlying SQL query and it was adding an additional field to `GROUP BY`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)**() method to get unique values in Django

**Ex:**

```
Log.objects.annotate(date=TruncDate('created_at')).values('d‌​‌​ate').distinct()
```